# Sort a vector with a comparator which changes its behavior dynamically

Tags: sorting, vector, rust

I have a vector of a custom struct and a list of attributes to use for ordering that vector in descending priority. For example:

```
struct TheStruct {
    artist: String,
    title: String,
    date: String,
}

let order_vec: Vec<String> = vec!["artist".to_string(),"title".to_string(),"date".to_string()];
let item_vec: Vec<TheStruct> = Vec::new();
```

I want the vector to be ordered as given by `order_vec`. In this example, it should first be ordered by the artists name, when this is equal it should be ordered by the title. I do not want to hard-code this ordering as `order_vec` changes dynamically.

I found `Vec::sort_by` which takes a compare function. How do I dynamically generate that function? Is there a way to do this without `sort_by`?

Comment: There are quite a few different parts of your problem. You apparently already found out about `sort_by()`: it lets you pass a custom comparator to do comparisons between elements. But then you have to parse a string specifying how the vector should be sorted, then you have to use this to do the actual sorting. Since there are so many things, this question is not focused enough. So please tell us: what exactly is your problem now?

Comment: Parsing the String is no Problem, thought about splitting it into a vec of strings and proccess each individually. The Problem is the second part: dynamically generate the compare function. The sort_string might contain any or none Attribute to sort with in decreasing priority. The order of these is dynamic as well. So the compare Funktion needs to be created dynamically and i dont now how to do this. Maybe there is another way without using build in sort methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I dynamically generate that function

You don't. You have a specific closure that has dynamic behavior inside of it.

Here, we have a list of sorts to apply. When we need to compare two items, we iterate through the list. We use [`Ordering::then_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html#method.then_with) to only apply the comparison when the previous comparison was `Equal`:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
enum Field {
    Artist,
    Title,
    Date,
}

struct TheStruct {
    artist: String,
    title: String,
    date: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut items: Vec<TheStruct> = vec![];

    use Field::*;
    let orders = vec![Artist, Title];

    items.sort_by(|a, b| {
        orders.iter().fold(Ordering::Equal, |acc, &field| {
            acc.then_with(|| {
                match field {
                    Artist => a.artist.cmp(&b.artist),
                    Title => a.title.cmp(&b.title),
                    Date => a.date.cmp(&b.date),
                }
            })
        })
    })
}
```

I used an enum for the fields because I didn't want to deal with what to do when one of the sorts is an unknown field.

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't know about `Ordering::then_width`, and I like the tie-in with `Iterator::fold`.