# Dynamic chained sorting of a vector by struct fields

Tags: sorting, rust

I have a struct

```
struct MyStruct {
    a: usize,
    b: String,
    c: String,
    d: usize,
}
```

I fill a vector with `MyStruct` objects and this vector then needs to be sorted by multiple fields of the structure. To make it harder, the sort priority is given as a list and can change, for example:

`sort_by = ["a", "b"]` means sort the vector by `MyStruct::a` values first, THEN (if the a values are equal) by `MyStruct::b` values

but it could also be

`sort_by = ["d", "c", "a"]` for example, which is of course sort by `MyStruct::d`, THEN `MyStruct::c`, THEN `MyStruct::a`.

So, it's an ORDER_BY basically...

How can I do that? Do I need external crates for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would define an `enum` with a variant for each member of your structure and then implement a `cmp_by` function like so:

```rust
enum MyStructKey {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn cmp_by(&self, other: &Self, keys: &[MyStructKey]) -> Ordering {
        match keys.split_first() {
            Some((MyStructKey::A, tail)) => {
                self.a.cmp(&other.a).then_with(|| self.cmp_by(other, tail))
            }
            Some((MyStructKey::B, tail)) => {
                self.b.cmp(&other.b).then_with(|| self.cmp_by(other, tail))
            }
            Some((MyStructKey::C, tail)) => {
                self.c.cmp(&other.c).then_with(|| self.cmp_by(other, tail))
            }
            Some((MyStructKey::D, tail)) => {
                self.d.cmp(&other.d).then_with(|| self.cmp_by(other, tail))
            }
            None => Ordering::Equal,
        }
    }
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5c2715f5ad60b18fca7ddd1ef348c5b3))

Assuming that you have more structures you want to compare like this, or that you have more fields, I would then create a macro that can generate this for you.

If you want to compare a vector, you can then use `cmp_by` in combination with `sort_by`:

```rust
let order = &[MyStructKey::B, MyStructKey::A, MyStructKey::C, MyStructKey::D];
let mut v = vec![a, b, c];
v.sort_by(|l, r| l.cmp_by(&r, order));
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=57dfe8c8f92f1ddf8509a9f691acabf7))

Comment: Wow, great answer, and even with working code... Thank you! :) I will now wrap my head around this

Comment: Thoughts on a duplicate of [Sort a vector with a comparator which changes its behavior dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46514082/155423) ?

Comment: @Shepmaster yup, seems right.